# Lotto random number generator

Tags: python, tkinter

Tkinter Application random numbers

How to you create a tkinter application that will generate 6 random numbers to create a set.
I want to know how do you make use of functions to create a tkinter application

Comment: Please provide some of your attempts, this is a question/answer website, not a "request algorithm" one.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't designed to be a place to provide tutorials or as a code delivery service. There are many sites out there that provide excellent tkinter tutorials. Feel free to come back if you need help with code that you've written that isn't working as you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid sampling a number multiple times, I'd recommend to use `random.sample`

```py
import random

set(random.sample(range(100), 6))
# {90, 77, 58, 4, 94, 16}
```